# write several iterations of an array in order

Tags: java, arrays, loops, text

I'm trying to fix a part of a program I'm writing, whose purpose is to read a text file and put its contents into a new text file a number of times equal to the integer written as the last line of the text file. When I check my output, instead of

```
abcd  
efgh  
ijkl  
mnop  
abcd  
efgh  
ijkl  
mnop
```

I'm getting

```
abcd  
abcd  
efgh  
efgh  
ijkl  
ijkl  
mnop  
mnop
```

I thought I could do this with a nested pair of `for` loops, but the second result is what I ended up getting. I'll paste the section of code I have making these loops below.
    
        `public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/MyPackage/sourcefile.txt"));
            File copy = new File("copy.txt");
            BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(copy));
            List<String> copiedLines = new ArrayList<>();
            String line;
            while ((line = read.readLine()) != null)
            {
              copiedLines.add(line);
            }
            int numberOfCopies = copiedLines.size() - 1;
            int runCopy;
            runCopy = Integer.parseInt (copiedLines.get(copiedLines.size()-1));
            for (int j=0; j < runCopy; j++)
            {
                for (int k=0; k < numberOfCopies; k++)
                {
                    write.write(line);
                    write.newLine();
                }
            }
            write.close();
            read.close();
        }
    }`

I'm confused as to why my array is writing element 0 to the new file the requisite number of times and then moving to element 1 and so on when I thought it would write element zero, then element 1, and so on, then loop back to element zero for the second iteration of the outer loop. Am I missing something obvious in my loop setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all

```
for (int i = 0; i < textLines.length; i++) {  
    numberOfCopies += 1;   
}
```

doesn't make sense, just use `numberOfCopies = textLines.length - 1` (or whatever it should be)

Then

```
for (int j=0; j < runCopy; j++) {  
    for (int k=0; k < numberOfCopies; k++) {  
        write.write(line);  
        write.newLine();  
    }  
}
```

Here you're missing the `line` declaration? Where is it? Maybe

```
line = textLines[k];
```

Anyway, using

```
for (int j=0; j < runCopy; j++) {
    for (int k=0; k < numberOfCopies; k++) {  
        final String line = textLines[k];
        write.write(line);  
        write.newLine();  
    }
}
```

You should be good to go. But I think you omitted too much from the question.

---

You're also creating a `String[]` array for nothing, you already have a `List<String>`.

```
List<String> copiedLines = new ArrayList<>();  
String line;  
while ((line = read.readLine()) != null)  
{
  copiedLines.add(line);  
}  
String[] textLines = copiedLines.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Just keep using the `copiedLines` `List`.

Comment: You're right, I should have used ```numberOfCopies = textLines.length - 1``` I think I just didn't see that when I was writing it. The line declaration is near the beginning of my method, I didn't think people would want the entire method, so I figured I'd just post the loop. Should I edit the original post to include the line declaration or should I post that portion down here in the comments?

Comment: @shuvool try using my suggestion.

Comment: I'm trying your suggestions, and running into issues with using the ```ArrayList``` not wanting to use a static ```get``` in a non-static context

Comment: @shuvool a static get? What do you mean?

Comment: the last element should contain only an integer. I need to parse this integer to determine the number of times the outer loop needs to iterate. I am not sure, but I think I'm supposed to use the ArrayList.get method to find the contents of the element in question, but it's giving me the error "Error:(45, 50) java: non-static method get(int) cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: @shuvool I'll post an entire example, so you can see it

Comment: Wait, I think I figured that issue out, I was being really dumb with what I was asking the compiler to do.

Comment: ok, I've reposted the revised code above, the problem I'm running into now is a ```NullPointerException``` inside the inner ```for``` loop for the line ```write.write(line);```

Comment: @shuvool if you apply my suggestion the code you posted will run fine. In this case the "line" variable will be null because of this "while ((line = read.readLine()) != null)" condition. The last iteration "line" is set to null

Comment: Just updating, I added your suggestion and along with the need to fix some other mistakes I made, the code works perfectly now, so thank you for the help.